# Randomzing the order of two scales using shuffle and foreach() in PHP

Tags: php, random, foreach, shuffle

I am a bit lost with my code and been trying to solve my problem for quite a while now. I think it cannot be that hard but still I cnnot wrap my had around it.
I have two questionnaires which I want to show to participants in a randomized order to avoid order effects in answering patterns.
So my aim is to have one questionnaire on page 1 and the other on page 2, in randomized order. My code so far is as follows:

```
    if (!isset($skalen)) { 
$skalen = array ( 
'UM02', // scale 1
'GM01' // scale 2
); 
shuffle ($skalen);
registerVariable($skalen);
$skalen[0];
}
```

on the next page, where the 2nd scale is to appear, I only have:

```
$skalen[1];
```

My problem is that the "shuffle" function does not shuffle my array. The scales always appear in the same order.
I also tried it with the foreach() function like this:

```
if (!isset($skalen)) { 
$skalen = array ( 
'UM02', // scale 1
'GM01' // scale 2
); 
shuffle ($skalen);
registerVariable($skalen);
}
foreach ($skalen as $kennung) {
question($kennung);
}
$kennung[0];
```

and on the naxt page:

```
$kennung[1];
```

If I do it like this the scales appear in random order but each scale appears two times (3 scales on page one of my questionnaire and 1 scale on page two). I Just don't know how to put an end to this. I am really no expert and basically took all the syntax from a manual for the program I'm using for my questionnaire.
I also tried to use "break" funtions to stop "foreach()" but I don't know how to tell "foreach()" to stop after mixing my scales once...

Would be great if someone could help. Thank you already :)

Comment: The values aren't automatically maintained over pages, so in the second page the results of the shuffle from the first page are gone.

Comment: On the second page you do not want `$skalen[1];`. Instead you want the one that has not been used yet so you need to store which one you are using in the first page somewhere where you can retrieve it, for example the session or a database.

Answer (score 0):

Okay thanks, problem is solved. I basically did not need the part with

```
foreach($skalen as $kennung)
```

And the questionnaires appeared duoble times because of a flaw that has nothing to do with the PHP code.

:)